# Split string into 2 strings after encountering the Nth vaue of a comma-delimited string

Tags: php, string, split

So, I have a comma delimited string which I want to split into two strings after count of x commas.

So, if my string was as follows:

> temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5, temp6, temp7, temp8, temp9, temp10

I want to split it into two strings after a count of 4 commas, I would expect:

```
$string1 = 'temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, ';

$string2 = 'temp5, temp6, temp7, temp8, temp9, temp10';
```

How can I achieve this in PHP?

Comment: Is the comma at the end of `$string1` intended? And do you mean comma separated or 'comma and space' separated, like in your examples?

Comment: Yes, the comma at the end of $string1 is intended, as afterward I intend to perform the following on both $string1 and $string2: `$newString1 = str_replace(",", "<br/>", $string1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this - one approach would be to explode the string and then implode slices of that array like this:

```
$x = 4;
$delim = ', ';
$str = 'temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5, temp6, temp7, temp8, temp9, temp10';
$parts = explode($delim,$str);
$string1 = implode($delim,array_slice($parts,0,$x)) . $delim;
$string2 = implode($delim,array_slice($parts,$x));
```

To me, this is the cleanest and most readable way to get the job done and does not require a loop.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun.  The `{4}` can be changed or substituted with a variable:

```
preg_match('/([^,]+,){4}/', $string, $matches);

$string1 = $matches[0];
$string2 = str_replace($string1, '', $string);
```

Comment: That's neat. I was playing with `preg_split` and lookbehinds, but then you get `Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length`. `preg_match` looks good.

Comment: nice answer but i think it should be `preg_match('/([^,]+, ){4}/', $string, $matches);`

Comment: What is about 'A,A,A,A,A,A,A,...' ?

Answer (score 0):

One other approach is to iterate on each char:

```
    $string = "temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5, temp6, temp7";

    $commacount = 0;
    $stringBefore = "";
    $stringAfter = "";
    $splitHasHappened = false;
    foreach (str_split($string) as $char) {

        if ($splitHasHappened) {
            $stringAfter .= $char;
        }
        else {
            $stringBefore .= $char;
        }

        if ($char == ",") {
            $commacount++;
        }

        if ($commacount == 4) {
            $splitHasHappened = true;
        }

    }

    echo "Before: $stringBefore - After $stringAfter"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple Function that takes 2 Arguments (The Comma delimited String and the Index at which to Split. The Result would be a numerically indexed Array with 2 keys: 0 and 1. $array[0] holds the first part and $array[1](https://eval.in/583334) holds the second part. Below is the function:

```
     <?php

        $strings    = "temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5, temp6, temp7, temp8, temp9, temp10";


        function splitAtIndex($commaString, $index){
            $arrBlended     = array();
            $arrStrings     = preg_split("#,\s?#", $commaString);
            if(!empty($arrStrings)){
                $partB          = array_splice($arrStrings, $index);
                $partA          = $arrStrings;

                $arrBlended[]   = implode(", ", $partA) . ", ";
                $arrBlended[]   = implode(", ", $partB);

            }
            return $arrBlended;
        }

        $arrSplitStrings        = splitAtIndex($strings, 4);
        $string1                = $arrSplitStrings[0]; //<== 'temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, '
        $string2                = $arrSplitStrings[1]; //<== 'temp5, temp6, temp7, temp8, temp9, temp10' 
        var_dump($arrSplitStrings);

        // DUMPS 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, ' (length=28)
          1 => string 'temp5, temp6, temp7, temp8, temp9, temp10' (length=41)
```

Test and Confirm the Result [HERE](https://eval.in/583334):

Comment: your result is missing part of the string.

Comment: look at his `$string1` and compare it to yours

Answer (score 0):

you can explode it into an array

```
$array = explode(",",$string);
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
  $string1[$i]=$array[$i];
} 
$string1 = implode(",",$string1);
for($i=4;$i<count($array);$i++){
  $string2[$i]=$array[$i];
}
$string2 = implode(",",$string2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer not using a loop for this. You would actually want some checking/validation of the input:

```
<?php

$count = 4;
$str = 'temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5, temp6, temp7, temp8, temp9, temp10';
$match = preg_match('/^([^,]+,\s?){' . $count . '}/', $str, $matches) ? $matches[0] : false;
if ($match) {
    $position = strlen($match);
    $str1 = substr($str, 0, $position);
    $str2 = substr($str, $position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `str_word_count`,`array_slice`, `array_filter` and `substr` functions:

```
$str = "temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5, temp6, temp7, temp8, temp9, temp10";

$comma_number = 4;
// finding the position of 4th comma
$pos = key(array_slice(array_filter(str_word_count($str, 2, ","), function($v){
    return $v == ",";
}), $comma_number - 1, 1, true));

$string1 = substr($str, 0, $pos + 2);
$string2 = substr($str, $pos + 2);

var_dump($string1, $string2);
```

The output:

```
string(28) "temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, "
string(41) "temp5, temp6, temp7, temp8, temp9, temp10"
```

Answer (score 0):

This Great For Me to split the specific comma sperated count values and add the br tag

```
<?php 
$string='temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5, temp6, temp7, temp8, temp9, temp10';
$delim = ',';
$x = 4;
$parts = explode($delim,$string);
$numberofloop=ceil(Count($parts)/$x);
for($i=0,$j=0;$i<$numberofloop;$i++){
        echo implode($delim,array_slice($parts,$j,$x))."<br>";
        $j=$j+$x;   
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no more direct or appropriate tool for this task than `preg_split()`.

To ensure that there will always be two strings returned from the native function call, allow an optional trailing comma and trailing space, allow less than N values to be matched in the "first half" string, and limit the number of output elements to `2`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/HUNIn))

```
$str = 'temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5, temp6, temp7, temp8, temp9, temp10';
$times = 4;

[$string1, $string2] = preg_split("/(?:[^,]+,? ?){0,$times}\K/", $str, 2);

var_dump($string1, $string2);
// string(28) "temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, "
// string(41) "temp5, temp6, temp7, temp8, temp9, temp10"
```

If you want to remove the trailing comma and space from the end of the first returned string, then move the \K to before the optional comma. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5RiO4))

```
[$string1, $string2] = preg_split("/(?:[^,]+\K,? ?){0,$times}/", $str, 2);
// string(26) "temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4"
// string(41) "temp5, temp6, temp7, temp8, temp9, temp10"
```